# Write to GL_ARRAY_TEXTURE_2D OpenGL interop fails

Tags: opengl, cuda

I need to write to [OpenGL GL_ARRAY_TEXTURE_2D](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) using CUDA graphics interop functionality.I use CUDA Driver API, CUDA version 7.5 .My GPU is NVIDIA Quadro K4000 with CC3.0 I create OpenGL array texture like this (5 layers):

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &_glArrayTexHandle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, _glArrayTexHandle);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA32F, m_viewportWidth, m_viewportHeight, 5, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
```

Then on CUDA side I create graphics image resource for that texture to be used with CUDA surface :

```
checkCudaErrors(cuGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&m_cudaToGL_TEX_ARRAY_Resource, _glArrayTexHandle, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, CU_GRAPHICS_REGISTER_FLAGS_SURFACE_LDST));
assert(m_cudaToGL_TEX_ARRAY_Resource);

checkCudaErrors(cuModuleGetSurfRef(&m_surfGLtexRef, m_module, "surfaceWrite"));
assert(m_surfGLtexRef);
```

During the renderloop I am mapping the resource and set reference between the array pointer and the surface to write to in the kernel:

```
   checkCudaErrors(cuGraphicsMapResources(1, &m_cudaToGL_TEX_ARRAY_Resource, 0));
   //write to layer number 3
   checkCudaErrors(cuGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(
   &m_cudaOffscreenFBOTextureArrayPtr, m_cudaToGL_TEX_ARRAY_Resource, 3, 0));
    assert(m_cudaOffscreenFBOTextureArrayPtr);

    checkCudaErrors(cuSurfRefSetArray(m_surfGLtexRef, m_cudaOffscreenFBOTextureArrayPtr, 0));



   ///launch the kernel:

    checkCudaErrors(cuLaunchKernel(function,
        blockDimX,
        blockDimY,
        1,
        block_size,
        block_size,
        1,
        0,
        NULL,
        args,
        NULL
        ));

    checkCudaErrors(cuGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &m_cudaToGL_TEX_ARRAY_Resource, 0));
    checkCudaErrors(cuCtxSynchronize());
```

The kernels looks like this:

```
surface<void, cudaSurfaceType2DLayered> surfaceWrite;
extern "C" __global__ void surfWriteFunc(int xOffset, int yOffset, int Width, int Height)

{

    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (x >= Width || y >= Height)
    {
     return;
    }

    float4 dataOut =  make_float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    surf2DLayeredwrite(dataOut, surfaceWrite, x * sizeof(float4), y, 3);

 }
```

I am trying to use CUDA [layered surface](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#surf2dlayeredread) write.At least that's what I suppose should be used with GL_ARRAY_TEXTURE_2D .Otherwise the NVIDIA docs have zero info on how to do it.The error I am getting is

**CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED** for every cuda method called during the rendering as seen above.I tried,for example to use cudaSurfaceType3D instead of layered,but it didn't help.It could be nice if anyone could shed some light on GL array textures interop with CUDA.

Comment: Without a repro case I am really struggling to understand how someoine could tell you what is wrong. CUDA API calls can return failures from earlier calls, so unless you either provide a complete example or pinpoint exactly where the failure starts, it is impossible to diagnose the issue. What happens if you run cuda-memcheck? Do you get a more constructive error from the kernel, for example?

Comment: My question is quite clear.The error comes exactly from the moment when the kernel has been launched.The extra code which I haven't included is OpenGL and CUDA contexts init + some rendering logic.But my question is more about "if and how CUDA supports layered interop write with OpenGL" But never mind,I think I figured out the issue.SO becomes a nasty place to ask questions.People downvote on the spot just because the haven't understood the question.

Comment: If you have a solution to this problem, could you please add it as an answer. As for voting, I own up - I voted to close this. And I did so because it really isn't clear what sort of answer you want. On the one hand you have what appears a kernel which is failing and destroying your CUDA context. If you want to know exactly what is causing it, you would need to supply a repro case or more precise information, which you haven't. On the other hand, the only  question appears to be ".It could be nice if anyone could shed some light on GL array textures interop with CUDA?" which is pretty broad

Comment: This is not broad at all.There is ability(at least the CUDA pure doc states) to map against GL_ARAY_TEXTURE_2D.The question is how?This is very narrow question.There are no many ways to do that.In fact,there is only one.Now,to me it seems that some people are trying to argue when they even don't possess a minimal level of expertise in the area which is talked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trials & errors I found how it works.First,it seems like CUDA doesn't allow layered surface write  when it comes to CUDA array pointer that maps to GL resource.So this code in kernel

```
surf2DLayeredwrite(dataOut, surfaceWrite, x * sizeof(float4), y, 3);
```

Is invalid as there is access to the layer zero only of the mapped array.
The valid code is

```
 surf2DLayeredwrite(dataOut, surfaceWrite, x * sizeof(float4), y, 0);
```

And therefore there is no reason to use surf2DLayeredwrite at all but just usual

2D surface write:

```
  surf2Dwrite(dataOut, surfaceWrite, x * sizeof(float4), y);
```

Now to the actual answer to the question "How to write to different layers of GL_ARRAY_TEXTURE_2D?

```
 checkCudaErrors(cuGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(
&m_cudaOffscreenFBOTextureArrayPtr, m_cudaToGL_TEX_ARRAY_Resource, **3**, 0));
```

Where "3" is the index of the layer in the mapped array texture to  write to.
I haven't find a way to select layer index from within the kernel.Currently it looks that it is only possible to do on the host.

Answer (score 0):

This ansver comes late, but maybe it helps someone...

I haven't tried GL_ARRAY_TEXTURE_2D, but I can say that at least GL_TEXTURE_3D texel indexing will work dynamically inside a CUDA kernel (starting from compute_20,sm_21 and CUDA 5.0, probably also CUDA 4.1 and CUDA 4.2).

However, there is one gotcha you need to know with three dimensional textures: you have to compile your CUDA program in release mode, not in debug mode.

Comment: Oh,really?In release?Are you sure this is not a bug?

Comment: Sure, this is the way which saved me with GL_TEXTURE_3D and C++ Visual Studio 10. A bug? well, I think CUDA has lots of bugs...